# How to identify the same number in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a binary matrix, it looks like this:

```
A = [ 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
      1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1; ]
```

But when I try to put `A` into a calculation, I only can use vector `B`, which 
is the row sum of matrix `A` into calculation. `B` looks like this:

```
B=[ 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1];
```

But I still want to carry the information about which "1" comes from which row of matrix `A`. I want to know is there any way to add additional conditions to vector `B`, so that vector `B` still can carry the information from matrix `A`, that is which "1" comes from which "row" of matrix `A`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example output given your above inputs?  It's a bit difficult to understand what it is you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its @luis's idea.. i'm just adding little changes. Also i still don't know whether this is what OP wants.

Created a 3D matrix from luis's solution, So that both the binary values and row info are stored in B. If you want binary values, access slice 1. if you want row info, access slice 2

```
[B(:,:,1), B(:,:,2)] = max(A);
B(1,~all(B,3),:) = 0;

>> B

B(:,:,1) =

 1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1


B(:,:,2) =

 2   2   0   1   1   1   0   2   2   0   1   1   0   0   2   3   3
```

If you want a specific binary value and its row index, say for eg, 8th binary value and its corresponding row index,

```
>> B(:,8,:)

ans(:,:,1) =

 1


ans(:,:,2) =

 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `A` only contains `0` and `1` values,

```
[v, B] = max(A,[],1);
B(v==0) = 0;
```

gives

```
B =
 2    2    0    1    1    1    0    2    2    0    1    1    0    0    2    3    3
```

If there are more than one `1` value in a column, this gives the row index of the *first* one.

Comment: yes, this is a good way,but you misunderstand what I am said. I said I only can take vector B , which is also binary, into calculation. I just want to add additional condition to vector B, but the vector B itself is still binary.

Comment: You want to get the row information _only from your `B`_? But that's impossible!

Comment: Perhaps if you just renamed your `B` to something else or specified the indices as an additional row? Or one can easily convert the `B` here to the one in the OP's question.

Comment: what if add additional condition to the calculation?

Comment: @horchler, can you specify your idea. I do not quite understand.

Comment: @Angelababy, you could create a 3D matrix from luis's solution like this: `B = cat(3,v,B)` so that both the binary values and row info are stored in `B`. If you want binary values, access slice 1. if you want row info, access slice 2

Comment: @SanthanSalai, please specify your answer. I will vote for your answer, if it works.

Comment: @Angelababy - Please edit your question so that you show us what the expected output looks like.  Currently, I don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Angelababy: Simple. Using the `B` calculated here, do `B(B>0) = 1;` to convert it back to the one in your question. Or copy it first: `C = B;` `C(C>0) = 1;`.

Comment: @rayryeng, there is no specific expected results I want. I just want to know the result is related to which "1" in matrix A.

Comment: So given elements in the vector `B` which spans the same number of columns of `A`, do you want to determine the locations of those values that are 1 in the matrix `A` corresponding to those columns in `B` that are 1?  It's still very unclear and I asked for an example output.  What would the expected output be given the `A` and `B` variables you defined in your question?

Comment: @Angelababy, have added an answer take a look at it.